# To run sudo commands on a ec2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, sudo, jsch, pty

I cannot run "sudo su" on my ec2 client , I ssh into the client through a java program and run the command through a program.
I can run commands like "ls" and "ifconfig" though.

I get an error saying "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo".

How can I run the command, I am using Jsch for ssh to my ec2 instance.

Answer (score 6):

You can do "sudo" without pseudo-tty with JSch, by using the `-S` option to `sudo`.

See the [Sudo.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java) on the JSch website for a complete example.

(I'm the author of JSch.)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like by default Jsch doesn't allocate a pseudo-tty for the remote session - this can break some programs that expect to be run interactively. It looks like you might be able to use the [ChannelExec.setPty](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setPty%28boolean%29) function to request a pty - but I've not worked with Jsch and can't test this myself.

Comment: Just a note: I created some Javadocs for JSch, you might want to link http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html#setPty(boolean) instead.

Comment: @all, I am using ChannelExec.setPty but afterwards I fail to ssh and get the message "Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer". Can you please guide me what I am doing wrong?