# passing a password to a shell script over JSCh

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I want to login into a remote machine and execute a shell script. That script will prompt for user id and password at run time.

Is it possible to do this with JSch?

Comment: What rights do you have on the remote computer ? Are you logging as root ? Can we assume the remote computer is in linux ?

Comment: If you are trying to execute "sudo su" command on remove Linux, then you will run into problems with JSch. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441637/to-run-sudo-commands-on-a-ec2-instance

Comment: For a better understanding: If you're connected on the computer, do you want run an extra shell script that shows you a prompt for login data and password?

Comment: i connect to a remote machine using ssh and i execute a script which is interactive, script asks user name and password.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple points to consider here:

- To connect to the server, you'll use a JSch Session, and then an `exec` channel (i.e. [ChannelExec](http://epaul.github.com/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/index.html?com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelExec.html)), giving the name of the script as the command.
- Then the script will try to read the password. You'll have to pass it on the channel's output stream, which is connected to the script's input stream.
- The script might try not to read from standard input, but from the terminal. If so, you'll need to enable a "pseudo terminal", using the method `setPty(true)`, and maybe even setting the terminal type with the other methods. Of course, this will also depend from the SSH server supporting this, but if you can use other SSH programs to do this, it should work.

Comment: hi can you please share a sample for getting password as input.